# Share login status between WordPress blog and RoR app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress, authentication, integration

I'm using `devise` for authentication in my Rails application.  I have a WordPress installation for the blog portion of the project (because I need several WP plugins).

Is it possible to integrate the user authentication from the RoR application into the blog, so that when someone logs into the app, then goes to the blog, their signed it status remains and shows up.

If that's possible, it should also be possible for them to log in while viewing the blog and then go straight to their page when they go to the app, right?

Comment: I'm working on finding an answer to the same question right now, but you might want to check out this link: http://www.igvita.com/2007/07/04/integrating-wordpress-and-rails/ I know such things are possible. Good luck.

Comment: This is possible, actually. This is the best resource I've found on the topic: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8887/sso-authentication-integration-with-external-directory-service. Anu's answer there should be everything you need!

Answer (score 0):

You have to store session information about WP and Rails session in one storage and check WP auth cookies on Rails application.